# Program that displays all multiples of 7 between 1 and 100 C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

How to write this program with `switch` condition statement instead of `if`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if ((i % 7 == 0) && (i > 0)) {
      cout << i << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `switch (i) { case 7: case 14: case 21: /* etc... */; break; default: /* all others */`?

Comment: Why do you want to use `switch`?  The `if` statement is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude doesn't this require you to know and list all the numbers divisible by 7? If I ask you to write the same program for all numbers < 10000, your answer becomes... cumbersome.

Comment: @OwenHempel That's the joke.

Comment: @OwenHempel That's kind of the point. There is simply no need or use for a `switch` statement here. Either it will be something like mine which does not scale well, or something like in [paweldacs answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41367070/440558) which is just a cumbersome `if` statement. If it's a requirement for a school assignment then it's made by an obnoxious teacher who apparently dislikes his or her work, or his/hers students.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You made my day with "cumbersome if statement". Thank you :) I just did what OP asked :) I don't support such solution, but for syntax learning purposes everything is fine from my POV.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking for should be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>  // this is for std::cin and std::cout (standard input and output)

using namespace std; // to shorten std::cout into cout

int main() {

    cout << "multiples of 7 lower than 100 are:" << endl;
    for ( int i=1 ; i<=100 ; i++ ) {
        switch ( i%7 ) {
            case 0:                // this case 0 is similar to if ( i%7 == 0 )
                cout << i << " ";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output will then be:

```
multiples of 7 lower than 100 are:
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84 91 98
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++)
    {
        switch(i % 7)
        {
            case 0:
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Online compilation: http://ideone.com/uq8Jue

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are a little unfamiliar with a switch statement. A switch statement is like an if-else statement, except that it isn't a Boolean argument. So essentially it asks: Tell me the value of . And then for each case (possible outcome), it has a follow up action.

So you want to ask: tell me the value of the number, modulus 7. If it is zero, add one to the counter. If it is 1, do .

So your code should have a general structure of:

```
Switch(i%7):
   Case 0{increment counter or display to std. out or store in array}
   Case 1{other action}
```

Comment: _"A switch statement is like an if-else statement"_ Not really, no

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well if you read on, there's an explanation... I'm trying to simplify it for someone. The finer details aren't as important as the concept.

Comment: It's the concept I'm having difficulty with. Thinking of a `switch` statement as "like an if-else statement" will likely lead to misusing it, because that is not what it is for.

Comment: Quote the whole sentence, as the second half of it makes the "like a if else" part make more sense. It's not "exactly equivalent to", nor is that the intent of the sentence

Comment: All you say is "except that it isn't a Boolean argument", which is not the point of the distinction. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to replace the `if` statement with `switch/case` statement for your case. But I think you have some misunderstanding about where to use `if` and where `switch/case` statements. I will suggest you use this statement as they are used in real life.

Use `if`, if you're going to check the condition. For example:

`if (a > b){...}` or `if (a == 7){...}` or `if (functionReturnsTrue()){...}`

The `switch/case` statement could be used when you have a set of conditions and the logic is different for each element in that set. For example:

```
enum HttpMethod {
  GET,
  POST,
  PUT,
  DELETE,
};

...

void handleHttpRequest(HttpRequest req)
{
  ...
  switch(req.getHttpMethod())
  {
    case GET: handleGETRequest(req); break;
    case POST: handlePOSTRequest(req); break;
    case PUT: handlePUTRequest(req); break;
    case DELETE: handleDELETERequest(req); break;
    default: throw InvalidHttpMethod(); // in case when noone corresponds to the variable
  }
}
```

Of course, you can write the same using `if` statement, but `switch/case` statement also have some compilation effects. When you `switch` the variable of `enum` type, you might get a compiler warning at least, if you dont check your variable for all possible flows.